# Where can I find a proof of this theorem in (introductory) real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

The following is a standard theorem in real analysis:

Let $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ be a continuous function on the open region $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and any open set $V \subseteq U$ such that also $\overline{V} \subseteq U$ there exists a continuous function $g(x_1, ...,x_n)$ with the following 4 properties:

1) $g$ is smooth on $V$

2) $g|_{U \setminus V} = f|_{U \setminus V}$

3) $\max_{x \in \overline{V}}|f(x) -g(x)|\le \varepsilon$

4) $g$ is smooth at every point $f$ is

Does this theorem have a name? I have been trying to find a reference with a proof but no luck. Could anyone give me a reference to a proof? I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Something really similar is proved as **Theorem 2.5** in M. Hirsch's book *Differential topology*.

Comment: @Siminore Thank you, very helpful. What I ask is a special case of theorem 2.4.